# Android paging works not as expected

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging, android-paging-library

I tried to use paging in my project. Unfortunately, it works not as I expected. I expected that the **liveDataObserver** will work after **callBack.onResult**.But in fact, the liveDataObserver observes immediately when the **loadInitial** finished.The **callBack** works later, and didn't post data to the observer.

The code:
First I wrote a class extend **PageKeyedDataSource** and interface **SingleCreator**

```
public class MyPagingDataSource<T> extends PageKeyedDataSource<Integer, T>

public interface SingleCreator<T> {
    SingleSubscribeProxy<Page<T>> createSingle(int page, int pageSize);
}
```

Then the constructor of **MyPagingDataSource**:

```
public MyPagingDataSource(SingleCreator<T> singleCreator) {
    this.singleCreator = singleCreator;
}
```

And override loadInitial:

```
@Override
public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams<Integer> params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<Integer, T> callback) {
    singleCreator.createSingle(1, params.requestedLoadSize)
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Page<T>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Page<T> ts) {
                    callback.onResult(ts.list, ts.pageNumber, ts.total, ts.pageNumber - 1, ts.pageNumber + 1);
                    Timber.d("registerLiveData" + ts.list.size());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    try {
        //when I add this, observer will work after callback
        //And if not observer works before callback.onResult
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then the **datasourceFactory** is just newInstanced in viewModel:

```
   public LiveData<PagedList<MyData>> page = loadPageData();

   public LiveData<PagedList<MyData>> loadPageData() {

    return new LivePagedListBuilder<>(new DataSource.Factory<Integer, MyData>() {

        @Override
        public DataSource<Integer, MyData> create() {
            return new HBPagingDataSource<>((page, pageSize) -> loadPageSingle(page, pageSize));
        }
    }, 2).build();
}
```

the **single**

```
    private SingleSubscribeProxy<Page<MyData>> loadPageSingle(int pageNum, int pageSize) {
    return mModel.loadMyDates(pageNum, pageSize)
            .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
            .as(autoDisposable(this));
}
```

at **fragment**

```
    mViewModel.page.observe(this, myDatas -> {
        Timber.d("registerLiveData%s", myDatas.size());
        myAdapter.submitList(myDatas);
    });
```

Maybe related things:

- I wrote **subscribeOn** and **observeOn** in retrofit's callAdapter
- The viewModel is a scopeProvider since I'm using autoDispose

I tried some example in github. And it seems, the setValue for pageLivedata is always work after loadInitial. In this case, how can I use **single**?

Answer (score 1):

It's seems solved.

The error is because schedule the thread using rxjava.
It makes single and datasource work in different thread.
In this case, callback onResult run after the observer.

So, I updated the callAdapter where I wrote subscribeOn and observeOn for single.
Filter by className when It's Page class, it won't do subscribeOn and observeOn.

Now the conclusion is, let paging handle the thread.